# How to plot monthly sales data correctly?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the monthly sales data with RStudio, but the dates on the x-axis are not showing correctly.

My code :-

```
uc_ts_plot <- ggplot(monthly_sales, aes(DATE,DAUTONSA)) + geom_line(na.rm=TRUE) + 
  xlab("Month") + ylab("Auto Sales in Thousands") + 
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format(format= "%b-%Y"),
               breaks = date_breaks("1 year")) + 
  stat_smooth(colour = "green")

uc_ts_plot
```

I expect the dates on the x-axis to be displayed as Jan-2011, Jan-2012, as shown [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/343096_90b218e393454f79a5012e7ad0913e76.html).

All I'm getting is a 0001-01 at the left end and a 0002-01 at the right end of the x-axis.

Comment: use the `scales` package to `scale_x_date`. More info found here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html

Answer (score 1):

The plot which is shown is filtered between year 2011 and 2018 whereas the data you have is from 1967.

The below code produces the exact plot

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)

monthly_sales %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE)) %>%
  filter(year(DATE) >= 2011 & year(DATE) < 2018) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(DATE,DAUTONSA) + 
  geom_line(na.rm=TRUE) + 
  xlab("Month") + ylab("Auto Sales in Thousands") + 
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format(format= "%b-%Y"),
               breaks = date_breaks("1 year")) + 
  stat_smooth(colour = "green")
```

[image]

You can remove the `filter` step to plot data for all the years but then it clutters the x-axis with lot of labels.

Comment: I tried this, but instead of Jan-2011, Jan-2012, it shows Jan-0011, Jan-0012. What could be the reason?

Comment: @ak9977 Are you using the same data as shown in the link because I downloaded the data from there and it worked for me.